# How to delete records from two tables with `@OneToMany` relation?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using JPA and Spring Data to perform CRUD operations. Find below the details:

**Primary table:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "university")
public class University implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pk.university", 
               cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
               fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Student> tagDetailReaders = new HashSet<Student>(0);
}
```

**Foreign key table:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
@AssociationOverrides({ @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.university", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "university_id")) })
public class Student implements Serializable {

}
```

**Spring data code to delete the records:**

```
University entity = universityDao.findAll().get(0);
universityDao.delete(entity);
```

**I am getting following error:**

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.available(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.available(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.available(ReadAheadInputStream.java:230)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.clearInputStream(MysqlIO.java:954)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2531)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2758)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2826)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2082)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2212)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2148)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4126)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:503)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1070)
```

Could somebody let me know why I am getting stackoverflow error?

**NOTE:** It works fine if I change fetch type from `EAGER` to `LAZY` and set `orphanRemoval=true`. Please let me know if this is the only way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The findAll() method is loading ALL students associated with ALL universities, which is probably why you are getting a StackOverflow error. That is why it goes away when you use LAZY fetch-type, since ALL students will not be loaded initially.